# YII2 createAbsoluteUrl составление ссылки с 2 переменными

Tags: yii2

Необходимо сделать ссылку с 2 GET переменными по сути так:

```
createAbsoluteUrl(['site/about', 'id' => 1, 'post' => 2])
```

но получается какая то белеберда, если так:

```
createAbsoluteUrl(['site/about', 'id' => 1])
```

то все работает, как же всетаки добавить 2-у переменную

Comment: Покажите что вы хотите, какая 'белеберда' получается, и какие правила для формирования ссылок.

Comment: Говорят вроде же изменили абсолютУрл... не?  http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/yii2-izmenenija-v-rabote-s-url  ..... в итоге надо бы писать `yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['site/about', 'id'=>1,'post'=>'2'])` .........напишите весь код который используете.....ибо например `<?php echo Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/confirm', 'id' => 123,'code' => 333]) ;?>`  работает вполне себе

Comment: код: `Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/about', 'username' => $this->username, 'verification_email' => $this->validation_email])`    в результате получаем: 
`www.mysite.com/frontend/web/site/about?1%5Busername%5D=proba  `   username есть а второго нету

Answer (score 1):

У меня код

```
<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['site/about', 'username' => 'aaa', 'verification_email' => 'xxx@bbb.cc']) ?>
```

формирует правильную строку

```
http://mysite/site/about?username=aaa&verification_email=xxx%40bbb.cc
```

Проверьте настройки urlManager в конфигурации.

Ну или чему равна переменная `$this->validation_email`